# zuul forwarding to different urls having same prefix

Tags: netflix-zuul

i have 2 instances of a service running on different ports

zuul forwarding properties for both of them are
for v1:

`zuul.routes.app.path=/app/**
zuul.routes.app.url=http://localhost:8081`

and for v2

`zuul.routes.app.path=/app/v2/**
zuul.routes.app.url=http://localhost:8082`

all my request to api/v2 are going into app/ and not to api/v2 is there any way to configure v1 one to ignore calls for api/v2 and/or forward it to v2 url given that path for v1 cant be changed

Answer (score 1):

Declare order of routes is important for zuul.

Described above happens because you have configured

```
zuul.routes.app.path=/app/**
```

eagerly consumes all responses. Try to configure in such order:

```
zuul.routes.app2.path=/app/v2/**
zuul.routes.app2.url=http://localhost:8082
zuul.routes.app1.path=/app/**
zuul.routes.app1.url=http://localhost:8081
```

So if it is specific call to

```
/app/v2/**
```

it will be matched first. If not, second match that consume all requests to

```
/app/**
```

...will be matched.

Note also, routes should be named differently:

```
app1, app2
```

You can also read about [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_strangulation_patterns_and_local_forwards). Hope this will help...